# Error: failed to load external entity at R

Tags: r

Pretty new to R and only scripting for hobby.

Tried this to Scrape data:

```
library("XML")

qb_fp <- readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$data
rb_fp <- readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/rb.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$data
wr_fp <- readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/wr.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$data
te_fp <- readHTMLTable("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/te.php", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$data
```

Getting the error:

> Error: failed to load external entity at R

Tried also to use httr but can't get it to work. My goal is putting this dataframes in a CSV.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `rvest` rather than `XML`.

As you will see, apparently simple tasks can require several steps and a lot of thought about how your data is structured.

Start by reading the HTML.

```
library(rvest)
p <- read_html("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php")
```

For the example URLs, the table you want is the first one on the page. So you could use `html_node("table")` followed by `html_table()`:

```
qb_fp <- p %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

Or you could use `html_table()` directly and take the first from the list:

```
qb_fp <- p %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```

Now there is some cleaning up to do. The HTML table has 2 header rows with merged cells. The headers you want are in row 2. So you can assign those names as headers, then subset the table to include rows 3 onwards like this:

```
qb_fp <- qb_fp %>% 
  setNames(.[2, ]) %>%
   .[3:nrow(.), ]
```

Now we have a problem: there are duplicate column names because ATT, YDS and TDS exist for both PASSING and RUSHING. We could fix them manually but for the sake of doing everything in one pass, let's use `janitor::clean_names()` which will convert names to lower case and append the duplicates with "_2":

```
library(janitor)
qb_fp <- qb_fp %>%
  clean_names()
```

One last problem: the values are of type character, not numeric. We can mutate them using `dplyr`. Here we select all columns except the first ("player"):

```
library(dplyr)
qb_fp <- qb_fp %>%
  mutate(across(-starts_with("play"), ~as.numeric(.x)))
```

So putting it all together:

```
qb_fp <- p %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  setNames(.[2, ]) %>% 
  .[3:nrow(.), ] %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(across(-starts_with("play"), ~as.numeric(.x)))

glimpse(qb_fp)

'data.frame':   72 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ player: chr  "Patrick Mahomes II KC" "Deshaun Watson HOU" "Josh Allen BUF" "Kyler Murray ARI" ...
 $ att   : num  38.4 33.4 36.1 34.8 36.9 34.7 25.2 38.4 38.8 33.4 ...
 $ cmp   : num  26.1 22.5 23.7 22.9 24.7 21.8 16.4 25 25.7 22.3 ...
 $ yds   : num  322 278 276 249 288 ...
 $ tds   : num  2.4 1.9 1.8 1.8 2.4 1.7 1.5 2.3 1.9 1.8 ...
 $ ints  : num  0.6 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.5 0.7 0.6 0.6 0.8 0.7 ...
 $ att_2 : num  4.2 6.5 6.4 7.9 2.8 8.7 11 1.8 3.3 5 ...
 $ yds_2 : num  18.9 35.3 33.2 44.2 12.1 46.4 63.1 2 13.9 26.3 ...
 $ tds_2 : num  0.2 0.3 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.4 0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1 ...
 $ fl    : num  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.2 ...
 $ fpts  : num  24.3 22.6 22.4 22.4 21.8 21.3 21 21 19.8 18.8 ...
```